# Combining Tab Bar, Navigation and Table View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So i would like to combine a Tab bar, Navigation and Table View controller. I have had difficulties finding an example that does this because i only found for tutorials for old versions of xcode such as 3 and 4.

How can i combine them all together? If you could provide me with example code, links ,videos anything is helpful thank you! I have also read that i need to have the table view as the root view if thats correct?

Any code that i would have to implement in the .h or .m file would be appreciated since i am a beginner in xcode!

**Note i am using storyboards!!**

Here is an example of what i want to achieve you can fast forward it to 00:53 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

i am using: Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you drag and drop a tabBarController in your storyboard, it will be attached to two viewControllers. Let's say you want the first viewController to be a navigationController: select it, press Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. Now, you'll see your viewController attached to a navigationController attached to your tabBarController. You can put a tableView inside it, if you want. Then you need to assign each viewController to your custom classes.

I think this tutorial will help you a lot: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1. In fact, it uses tabBar, navigation and tableView.

Comment: What a wonderful tutorial just what i needed with detailed explanation!! Thank you! @Leandro

Answer (score 1):

There is a  great tutorial series about iOS programming in [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-course/). Tutorial #11 is  detail instruction for embedding navigation controller in tab bar controller to build complete app. I think that tutorials in AppCoda will be helpful to you.